# iPhone4 Crash log - EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: iphone, sdk, crash, sigabrt

My app keeps crashing when changing from a game screen back to the menu. I have no idea how to read the crash log, any help would be greatly appreciated. The cash only happens on while testing on a iphone 4, runs without issue on the 3g and 3gs.

`Incident Identifier: B358D8C0-0DBC-4454-BF00-2315A143040D
CrashReporter Key:   6e900bd59b40f1708778b028bd48e67e94fe40c2
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         noagendahumanresource [1128]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/18025566-3A5C-4D05-8C91-AB54F586E314/noagendahumanresource.app/noagendahumanresource
Identifier:      noagendahumanresource
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-03-10 16:15:23.259 -0600
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be caused by uncaught exception / memory leakage.

Follow these steps to debug:

1. first in XCode, **Build > Clean All Targets**
2. use **Build & Analyze** to find out any potential leakage
3. set breakpoints in several key program functions & see when does the app crash
4. use try & catch to catch exception
5. last, use **Run > Run with Performance Tool > Leaks** to find out actual leaks